# How to search a downloaded string of a website?

Tags: c#

I have downloaded the string and found the index but am not able to get the text which I am searching for. Here is my code:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http://www.gmail.com");
int ss = downloadedString.IndexOf("fun");
string mm = downloadedString.Substring(ss);
textBox1.Text = mm;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Expected input?  Expected output?

Comment: Afaik, gmail is all javascript driven, so if you're searching for "fun" that might be populated via ajax, and thus not in the original request.

Comment: Shouldn't it be https://mail.google.com? It's going to redirect.

Comment: I don't think the text is loaded via Javascript. Google always tries to reduce the number of requests needed to load a page as much as possible and text is something too trivial for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
 if (downloadedString .Contains("fun"))
    {
        // Process...
    }
```

Comment: after i press the submit button on a webpage then some data appears and when is see it in a source code it is appeared in <td><span "data">.....so how can i get this data ?? Actually i am searching something on webpage from c# and i want to get those results...please help i searched alot but couldn't find it

Comment: you need to extract html tag from string first and then have to do search on new string.. this link may help you http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Visiting [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) will perform 3 directs. Try the following url instead:

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2

Also, consider using a proper HTML Parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).